# How search sentence with match sql

Tags: sql

I need to seek a sentence in my database.

I use "LIKE" :

```
SELECT * FROM `TABLE` WHERE `TEXT` LIKE '%toto tata titi%';
```

but, i need to use "MATCH" :

```
SELECT * FROM `TABLE` WHERE match(`TEXT`) AGAINST ('+toto +tata +titi' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM `TABLE` WHERE match(`TEXT`) AGAINST ('+toto tata titi' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

But the query with "MATCH" does not return the same number of records with a "LIKE".

So How to search a sentence with match ?

Answer (score 0):

These two statements are very different:

```
WHERE `TEXT` LIKE '%toto tata titi%'
WHERE match(`TEXT`) AGAINST ('+toto +tata +titi' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

The first looks for a string that has 14 characters `'toto tata titi'` that look just like that.  It will not match `'tata titi toto'`.

The second does a search word by word, so it will match `'tata titi toto'` and `'toto and xxx tata yyy titi'` as well.

The equivalent `like` logic would be more like:

```
WHERE `TEXT` LIKE '%toto%' and
      `TEXT` LIKE '%tata%' and
      `TEXT` LIKE '%titi%'
```

This isn't exactly the same, because this will match `'tototatatiti'` which the `match` version will not.  But it is probably close enough for what you want.

Comment: Ok, but how to search 'toto tata titi' witch a match ? :/

Comment: @user3337165 . . . Your `match` should do that.